# Stripe Webhooks return 302 on laravel application, using spatie webhook

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am attempting to set up stripes webhooks in my laravel application. I have pulled in spatie's webhook package to help out, link below.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks

My endpoint on stripe looks like

https://myapp.ca/stripe/webhook

Dev

my routes

```
Route::stripeWebhooks('stripe/webhook');
```

I have included the key in webhook config,

and included in the verifyCsrfToken

```
'stripe/*',
```

When I send a test I get

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://myapp.ca/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to https://myapp.ca/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="https://myapp.ca/login">https://myapp.ca/login</a>.
    </body>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It *looks* like you have your endpoint behind an authentication wall.  It means that if you try and visit that page, it'll make you login first.  The endpoint has to be public facing.

Comment: I get that, but I am not sure why or how.  I likely forgot something small, I just can't figure it out, or it's not standing out for me.